# What is the parameter of the beforeSend jquery function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have been seeing some examples of the `beforeSend` callback function.
These examples use sometimes an input parameter: `beforeSend:function(req)` or `beforeSend:function(xhr)`.

I suppose that this parameter is the `XMLHTTPRequest` of the jquery request, but when I try these examples it seems that the `xhr` or the `req` objects are `null`.

Is it necessary to create the `xhr` parameter and initialize it before calling the execution of the jquery object?

Here is the query that I am trying:

```
function make_basic_auth(un, pss)
{
  var tok = un + ':' + pss;
  var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
  return "Basic " + hash;
}

$('#loginform').submit(function()
{
    $.ajax
    (
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'my.ip.address',
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings)
            {   
                var username = $('.username').val();
                var password = $('.passcode').val();
                var auth = make_basic_auth(username, password);

                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization",  auth);
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            },
            success: function (){
               alert("ok");
            },
            error: function (){
               alert("no");
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: I'd recommend referring to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you MrObrian, I have read it, and my question still the same.

Comment: Does the request work without the beforeSend property set?

Comment: I just added a `beforeSend: function(xhr){}` entry to a generic ajax call and got the jqXHR object in my xhr variable. It might help if you could create a jsFiddle that reproduces your problem.

Comment: not sure? do a console.log(arguments) and you will see

Comment: @ErikReppen yes Erik, the request work without the beforeSend property, but I need this property to set the basic authentication headers.

Comment: @LynHeadley I just added the code of the query to my main question. Thank you

Comment: I am not getting any error now, but the request is failing, how can I know what is wrong? is there any mean to see the type of the error?

Comment: @LynHeadley I am using version 1.8.2

Comment: @wirey I added console.log(arguments) at the end of the function beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) and I see only [Object, Object] in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "google.com",
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.error = function(){
            alert("failed");
        }
    }
})​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kXerD/

Here, I am saying that before sending the request, add a error handler to this request. JQuery provides the objects of jqXHR and settings that is relevant for this request. We don't need to initialize them.

Comment: No one explained the example of `settings`